# What is the bandwidth cost of running a full node?

Tags: full-node, monerod, bandwidth

Simply...how much bandwidth will I use when running a full node at home, without mining?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bandwidth utilization greatly depends upon whether or not inbound ports are opened up or not.

On a fast 10gbit+ VPS with inbound ports opened up, I see 280 GB inbound and 250 GB outbound used.

On a residential connection with 8 outbound connections and zero inbound, I see less than 10GB inbound / outbound used in 30 days.

Comment: Could you comment on whether you see a significant increase in bandwidth usage since RingCT transactions were enabled (January 10th)? Any idea by how much? Thanks.

Comment: Over the past few days I'm seeing an average of 550 Mbytes down per day and about 1200 Mbytes up per day. There's a lot of variation on the outbound side, ranging between 300 Mbytes and 2800 Mbytes per day. I'd say that overall, I don't see a lot more bandwidth usage for a full node with unlimited bandwidth and open inbound ports.

Answer (score 13):

You can set this when you start the daemon I believe:

Typing `monerod --help` and scrolling down shows you there are these options:

[image]

So to limit your bandwidth you could type: `monerod --limit-rate 100` to limit up and downstream activity to 100kB/s each way. Or you can set them individually as shown.